# How to pass multiple selected UITableview cells into a separate view so the user sees the selected data

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

i am completely new to passing data but try to achieve that when user has selected multiple UITableView cells and the button clicked it takes each cells image and text value to any separate view controller. I try to achieve i order overview.I am looking fro any useful help via tutorials or any kind of help offered.

Thanks for your kind help to a total beginner

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet to transfer data between viewControllers is hooking into the segue-infrastructure by overwriting the `prepareForSegue` method. In there you can access the `destinationViewController` and set the properties you want to transfer like text, images, etc.

You would need to setup segues in the IB, give them an identifier and then you are able to check for that identifier to transfer the needed data:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"myIdentifier"]) {
        MyViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
        // collect all needed images and texts 
        // transfer them, e.g.
        controller.customStringProperty = @"Transfering data";

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can choose among multiple Options.

1st you can use Core Data, to save everything you want then retrieving your saved objects from any viewController class

2nd or you can choose `NSNotificationCenter` class to transmit your code to other Views,

Even though sometimes you  need to work with both Core Data & `NSNotificationCenter`

I recommend to you 2 Books

- Beginning iPhone Development with swift, Chapter 13: Basic data persistence
- Core Data by tutorials iOS 8 and Swift

Hint `NSNotificationCenter` Class isn't used for Pushing Notifications

Check This [tutorial](http://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/10/08/fundamentals-of-nsnotificationcenter-in-swift/) for `NSNotificationCenter`